# Convert x and y array to Point

Tags: java, arrays, point

I have 2 arrays namely `x` and `y` and I wish to convert them into one `Point` array.

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
public class Point {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         Point[] objectPoints;
         double x[] = {3,4,5};
         double y[] = {4,5,6};

         for (int i = 0;i < 2; i++) {
             objectPoints[i] = new Point(x[i],y[i]);
         }
     }
}
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: _"Doesn't seem to be working"_ is insufficient.  Describe exactly what you're seeing, what you expect, and why you think there's a problem. If there is an error message or stack trace, copy/paste the information into your post (format as code for readability).  Without that basic information nobody can help you.

Comment: You are calling a constructor that does not exist.

Comment: Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: I don't see where you initialize your     objectPoints array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Point` class doesn't have a constructor, your `objectPoints` array is never initialized and your loop only goes from 0 to 1. What you want is something like this:

```
public class Point {

    private double x, y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point[] objectPoints = new Point[3];
        double x[] = {3,4,5};
        double y[] = {4,5,6};

        for (int i = 0; i < objectPoints.length; i++) {
            objectPoints[i] = new Point(x[i], y[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what you think is wrong, but here are some obvious issues:

You haven't defined a constructor for `Point`, or any instance variables in `Point` to hold the x and y coordinates, and

```
for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
```

You're headed in the right direction but you're missing some basics.

Answer (score 0):

So, finally your code should look something like that:

```
class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        double x[] = {3, 4, 5};
        double y[] = {4, 5, 6};
        Point[] objectPoints = new Point[x.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            objectPoints[i] = new Point(x[i], y[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `Point` type array should have a size to create indexes for the values to be inserted, the size of array should be known.
2. You can only pass `int` values to `Point` constructor while you are passing `double` values.
3. Dont use a class name `Point` because you are Using the builtin java `Point` in your program.

   ```
   public class ThePoint {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       double x[] = {3, 4, 5};
       double y[] = {4, 5, 6};
       Point[] objectPoints = new Point[x.length];
       for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
           objectPoints[i] = new Point((int) x[i], (int) y[i]);
       }
       System.out.println(objectPoints[0].x);
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the 2 arrays have the same length or not. Secondly, you can't name your project `Point` since this name is kind of used by the `Point` existing class.

```
public class MyPoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Point[] objectPoints;
    double x[] = {3,4,5};
    double y[] = {4,5,6};

    if(x.length != y.length)
        throw new //MyTypeError
    else//the x and y array share the same length
    {
        objectPoints = new Point[x.length];
        for (int i=0; i < x.length; i ++)
        {
            objectPoints[i] = new Point(x[i],y[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use array with output you need to use ArrayList. And I think you shouldn't use class name Point that would cause some troubles in functions of the class

```
import java.lang.*;
/***********************************/
ArrayList<Point> objectPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
double x[] = {3,4,5};
double y[] = {4,5,6};
if (!(x.Length == y.Length))
    // YOU SHOULD DO THIS EVEN IF YOU'RE SURE THAT THEY ARE THE SAME
for (int i = 0;i < x.Length; i++) {
    objectPoints.Add(new Point((int)x[i],(int)y[i]));
}
```

Sorry I don't remember if it was add or insert because I'm working with a lot of languages at the same time :v :v

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Point {
  //you forgot variables to hold values
  private double x;
  private double y;

  //you forgot constructor
  public Point (double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    double x[] = {3, 4, 5};
    double y[] = {4, 5, 6};

    //just a check that x and y size should be equal
    if (x.length != y.length) {
      throw new Exception("points x array is not equal to points y array");
    }

    Point[] objectPoints = new Point[x.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < objectPoints.length; i++) {
      objectPoints[i] = new Point(x[i], y[i]);
    }
  }
}
```